# VBA does not choose right Worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I try to insert zeros for empty cells in a range of another worksheet with a button(=Tabelle Nullen + Pivots aktualisieren). But instead of choosing the right Worksheet VBA inserts the zeros into the same Worksheet where the button is. Can someone explain what is the reason for it and how I can solve it?

Thank you in advance!

```
    Option Explicit

Dim Zelle As Range

  'NULL Werte bei Spalten US bis AA suchen und durch 0 ersetzen
    With Sheets("Tabelle")
  For Each Zelle In Range("K2:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Trim(Zelle.Value) = "" Then Zelle.Value = "0"

    Next

   End With

   'Alle Pivot-Tabellen aktualisieren


    With Sheets("PivotHaendlerMonat").PivotTables("PivotHaendlerMonat").PivotCache.Refresh
       End With
       With Sheets("Pivot_AnfragenMonat").PivotTables("PivotHaendlerRequestMonat").PivotCache.Refresh
       End With

    MsgBox ("Alle Tabellen fertig aktualisiert!")

    End Sub
```

[image: You can see how the 0s are insert in this worksheet. But should be in "Tabelle"]

Comment: `Range` doesn't care about your `With`-statement, it will always use the active sheet. You have to write `.Range` - the dot tells the VBA compiler to use the object of the `With`-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a `With` statement, you need to prefix members (such as `Range`) of the specified object with `.`, otherwise it'll default to `ActiveWorksheet`.

```
With Sheets("Tabelle")
  For Each Zelle In .Range("K2:O" & .Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Trim(Zelle.Value) = "" Then Zelle.Value = "0"
  Next Zelle
End With
```

Also, the two empty `With` statements at the end of your code are redundant - you probably meant to use:

```
Sheets("PivotHaendlerMonat").PivotTables("PivotHaendlerMonat").PivotCache.Refresh
Sheets("Pivot_AnfragenMonat").PivotTables("PivotHaendlerRequestMonat").PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation. It works now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You correctly have a `With` statement before your code, but do not use it correctly.
When using a with statement, it is the standard prefix when an empty `.` is used. Consider this example, if you have two sheets, and sheet1 is your active sheet:

```
With Sheet2
    Range("A1").Value = "2"
End With
```

will post on sheet 1. Whereas

```
With Sheet2
    .Range("A1").Value = "2"
End With
```

Will correclty post on sheet 2.

Your correct code is:

```
    With Sheets("Tabelle")
        For Each Zelle In .Range("K2:O" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row)
    If Trim(Zelle.Value) = "" Then Zelle.Value = "0"
```